# using sed with variables to replace quoted string in bash

Tags: sed

Working in bash. I have a `file.txt` with contents in the following format.

```
default=60.0,
default=False,
default=(0.2, 0.2, 0.3, 1.0),
default="blend",
default="/path/to/directory")
```

There is other info on each line before and after what i am showing but this is the part i want to edit.  i am trying to replace the values following the equals sign and before the comma with values stored in a variable. i can make it work if i know all the info of line number, what to replace, and what replacing with beforehand but as soon as i start working with variables it all falls apart. i can use `sed -i '4s/default="blend",/default="burn",/' file.txt` to replace `blend` with `burn` on line 4 but how can i do this with variables?  i cant seem to find the right way to quote this. and obviously the data i am trying to replace is not consistent, some numbers, some strings, some quoted, some not, some bracketed, some not, some followed by `,`, some followed by `)`. focused on line 4 currently, if `var1=4` and `var2="burn"` and default= could be any of "blend, burn, or bump". so say i want to replace whatever follows `default=` with `"burn"` on line 4, `var1=4` `var2="burn"`

Desired output:

```
default=60.0,
default=False,
default=(0.2, 0.2, 0.3, 1.0),
default="burn",
default="/path/to/directory")
```

hopefully what i am trying to accomplish makes sense because i'm stuck. how can i make this work? doesn't have to use sed if there is another simple way.

edit:
contents of entire line are:
`parse.add_argument("-j", "--blend_type",    default="blend", choices=["blend", "burn", "bump"], help="type of blend the shader can do")`

using: `sed -r "$var1{s/(default=\")(.*)(\".*$)/\1$var2\3/p}" file.txt`

my output is `parse.add_argument("-j", "--blend_type",    default="burn")`

and i want it to be `parse.add_argument("-j", "--blend_type",    default="burn", choices=["blend", "burn", "bump"], help="type of blend the shader can do")`

i'm close but can't seem to keep the end of the line intact.

Comment: Please add your desired output (no description) for that sample input to your question (no comment).

Comment: please update the sample inputs with some sample before/after data on each line, in particular ... what's the delimiter between the `before`, `default=...` and `after` sections?

Answer (score 1):

> i can use sed -i '4s/default="blend",/default="burn",/' file.txt to replace blend with burn on line 4 but how can i do this with variables?

```
linenumber=4
from=blend
to=burn

# a bit extra: escape special characters
# https://stackoverflow.com/questions/407523/escape-a-string-for-a-sed-replace-pattern
from=$(printf '%s\n' "$from" | sed -e 's/[]\/$*.^[]/\\&/g');
to=$(printf '%s\n' "$to" | sed -e 's/[\/&]/\\&/g')

# Note the quoting
sed -i "${line}s/default=\"${from}\",/default=\"${to}\",/"
#        ^^^^^^                                            - used ${line} so that 's' is separate
#                        ^^       ^^          ^^     ^^    - double quotes within double quoting need to be escaped
#      ^                                                 ^ - double quotes so that ${..} are expanded
```

> ```
> sed -i '"$var1"s/default="blend",/default="burn",/' $f2
> ```

Variables are not expanded within single quotes.

> ```
> sed -i "$var1"s/default="*"/default="$var2"/ file.txt
> ```

Regex is not glob. `"*` matches **zero or more** `"` characters. It does **not** match anything, `*` matches zero or more of **preceding** character or group. A dot `.` matches anything, so you could `default=".*"` or better I would go with `default="[^"]*"`.

> ```
> sed -i ""$var1"s/default="*",/default="$var2",/" file.txt
> ```

Use an editor with syntax highlighting. Even stackoverflow syntax highlighting should hint you - `"` close the other `"`. To write `"` within double quotation, escape them `"\""`.

Comment: upvoted for making me realize i am still thinking about some things wrongly. not an ideal solution though as i may not know what the initial default value is.

Comment: `may not know what the initial default value is` Then match it with a regex.

Comment: ok it took me a bit to figure out how to get the starting value into a variable but once i did this worked a charm.  thank you sir not just for the right answer but also for helping me think differently.

Answer (score 0):

To expand the variables, place the sed statement in double quotes as opposed to single quotes. Also since you are using var1 to hold the line to process, place the proceeding substitution statement in {}:

```
sed -r "$var1{s/(^default=\")(.*)(\",?.*$)/\1$var2\3/}" file1.txt
```

Also, enable the regular expression interpretation with -r or -E and then split the line into three sections specified in parenthesis and substitute the line for the first section, var2 and then then the third section. Escape any double quotes in the text to change where required.

Comment: You don't need braces if there is a single address, though you'll need to disambiguate the variable reference like `${var1}s/..."`

Comment: ```sed -ri "$var1{s/(default=\")(.*)(\")/\1$var2\3/}" file1.txt``` This almost gets it done. at least it replaces the necessary bit, but it deletes everything on the line after the match.

Comment: Yeah. Use -i to commit the changes to the file. If the solution meets yours requirements. Please take the time to up vote and accept the answer.

Comment: I've amended the solution. Try it again.

Comment: new solution still drops off the end of line. also removed the ```^``` as the string i am working with is not the actual beginning of line.

Comment: Could really do with knowing the complete line as an example

Answer (score 0):

Assumptions/provisos:

- patterns to be searched and replaced can contain any printable characters which means ...
- said patterns may need to include escape characters to keep from clashing with `sed` delimters and constructs
- `default=<search_pattern>` only shows up once in a line

Sample data:

```
$ cat file.txt
abcde default=60.0, ABC
12345 default=False, ABC
STUVW default=(0.2, 0.2, 0.3, 1.0), ABC
@#%#@ default="blend", ABC
ABCDE default="/path/to/directory") ABC
```

One `sed` idea based on 2 variables (`var1` == search / `var2` == replacement):

```
sed -E "s/default=$var1/default=$var2/g" file.txt
```

Test case #1:

```
var1='"blend"'
var2='"burn"'
sed -E "s/default=$var1/default=$var2/g" "${infile}"
```

Generates:

```
abcde default=60.0, ABC
12345 default=False, ABC
STUVW default=(0.2, 0.2, 0.3, 1.0), ABC
@#%#@ default="burn", ABC                              # modified line
ABCDE default="/path/to/directory") ABC
```

Test case #2:

```
var1='\(0.2, 0.2, 0.3, 1.0\)'                          # must escape the parens
var2='[something different = 3.22]'
sed -E "s/default=$var1/default=$var2/g" "${infile}"
```

Generates:

```
abcde default=60.0, ABC
12345 default=False, ABC
STUVW default=[something different = 3.22], ABC        # modified line
@#%#@ default="blend", ABC
ABCDE default="/path/to/directory") ABC
```

Test case #3:

```
var1='"\/path\/to\/directory"'                         # must escape the forward slashes
var2='"\/a\/new\/directory"'                           # must escape the forward slashes
sed -E "s/default=$var1/default=$var2/g" "${infile}"
```

Generates:

```
abcde default=60.0, ABC
12345 default=False, ABC
STUVW default=(0.2, 0.2, 0.3, 1.0), ABC
@#%#@ default="blend", ABC
ABCDE default="/a/new/directory") ABC                  # modified line
```